# Evidence of neutral weak currents

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, weak-interaction, electroweak

Why is muonic anitneutrino, electron scattering an experimental evidence of the existence of neutral weak current? This is $\bar{\nu_{\mu}}+e^-\to \bar{\nu_{\mu}}+e^-$.

And why the electron antineutrino, electron scattering isn’t? This is $\bar{\nu_{e}}+e^-\to \bar{\nu_{e}}+e^-$.

I realize an s-channel scattering diagram of the first interaction is not possible due to lepton number conservation at vertices. Also, both s-channel and t-channel scattering diagrams are possible for the second interaction, but I don’t get how this has to do with the experimental evidence of neutral weak current.

My first hunch is, if we previously know that antineutrinos only interact with weak currents, and we observe the first interaction, it has to be due to a neutral weak current, otherwise charge wouldn’t be conserved at vertices (for only a t-channel diagram is possible). However, if the second interaction is observed, it could be due to a $W^-$ boson in the s-channel scattering (so no evidence for neutral weak currents).

Would this be correct or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! This is a good question, but you seem to have already answered it. That makes it lean into "check my work" territory, which we don't do here. Consider (a) moving your hunch to an answer, where the community can evaluate it, or (b) explaining conceptually why you think your hunch might be mistaken.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargamelle#Results_and_discoveries).